# Cancel Subscription Paypal API + Axios + React

Tags: reactjs, paypal, axios, paypal-subscriptions

I'm stuck with a Paypal Smart buttons error that says `401 (Unauthorized)`

The business solution is paid for and everything that should be authorized is.

This is the function I created. Anything in-between [ ] are placement holders of private info:

```
cancelSubscription = () => {
    axios({
        url: `https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/[USER_SUBSCRIPTION_ID]/cancel`,
        method: 'post',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer [FACILITATOR_ACCESS_TOKEN]" },
        data: { "reason": "test -- Not satisfied with the service" }
    })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(`Axios Call completed: ${res}`)
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your code, so the clientid, access token, and full response body+response headers (including a PayPal-Debug-Id) will all have to be looked at to troubleshoot a 401.  Submit this information to PayPal's support if you aren't going to post it here.